# Font Awesome Icons, How do you make them hyperlink?

Tags: css, wordpress

Im trying to make the Font Awesome icons hyperlink to a url any help is appreciated. The icons are on this Wordpress theme's homepage here: http://www.selfdoubelieve.com/ .. Where how do I make them hyperlink?

Comment: have you tried wrapping them in a `<a> </a>` tag?  like a normal hyperlink?

Comment: i.e. `<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fighter-jet"></i></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdrbqnLh/

Comment: I see where it works for jsfiddle, but not when I add that code to Wordpress, in fact the icon disappears and it becomes blank. Do I need to add that to a stylesheet maybe in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I think you theme doesn't include Font Awesome, it should be linked before you can use the icons, you can download the files here https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ and unzip files into your template directory (using cPanel or FTP), on on html/wp-content/themes/templateyouareusing/css. Then look on your template directory for head.php and edit it, search for the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css">` tags and copy one and put the name of the font-awesome.css. See if that allows you to use icons